# Vagrant machine slow network communication

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I'm running on pretty good PC machine

- Intel Xeon E5-2609
- 16GB
- Windows 7
- Decent Internet Connection (90ms ping, 35.45 Mb/s down, 6.77 Mb/s up)

I'm running Homestead Vagrant with a few extra install (ElasticSearch and Cassandra Services). I'm running it at default configuration with 2GB VM ram.

My application for testing purpose is connecting to a AWS server database. It takes double the time for me to fetch and reach to get the data if I actually run on a Nginx server Ubuntu pure (same network). Approx 5 seconds to fetch 48 items off an Eloquent query where as the Nginx server does it under 1.2s

I have my coworker machine running Ubuntu with Cassandra installed and when Fetch/Write its at about 3-4 seconds (no view or manipulation). We are on the same local area network.

I have since then increased the VM ram size to 4GB - and to no avail able to shrink the delay in HTTP request.

I have no clue what else to do next. Suggestions/Fix??

Comment: have you tried virtio-net adapter and 1Gbit/sec Intel driver? Do you use latest linux kernel?

Comment: @mikhailov as mentioned I'm using the homestead vagrant box configuration by default. so for the kernel its: Linux homestead 3.16.0-23-generic x86_64. and yes for the Intel Driver as I ran dmesg with the following output: [    1.556393] e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[   11.512684] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX

Comment: Is the host machine on Windows?

Comment: @mikhailov yes(hence the windows 7 explanation above)

Comment: I'd say that is the biggest bottleneck as Windows TCP/IP stack is slower. It is not correct to compare it with Linux.